# PHP: Must I use $this to access class properties?

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, class properties are accessed using the implicit parameter $this:

```
class Test {
    private $foo;
    public function __construct($val) {
        $this->foo = $val;
    }
}
```

But this (no pun intended) fails

```
class Test {
    private $foo;
    public function __construct($val) {
        $foo = $val;
    }
}
```

Do I have to use `$this` to access class properties in PHP (I'm guessing yes)? If so, why? Perhaps something to do with its dynamic nature? I know in Java, we can choose to do either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is covered in the manual.

Comment: @tereško And people wonder why the CV queue hit 100k... The question is already answered. Your close votes only add cruft.

Comment: @Boann since you seem oblivious about it - let me explain. Question which are already closed **don't end up in CV-queue.** Think of this as "removing garbage".

Comment: @tereško You haven't removed anything. Since you're oblivious about it, the votes reviewers spent closing this question could otherwise have been spent on some other "garbage".

Comment: @OP: nope, you must use `$that` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, yes, you must. PHP wasn't planned in this regard as OOP was tacked on gradually later. Since PHP doesn't have a syntax to declare local variables, field variables are distinguished by qualifying all accesses with `$this->`. It's similar to how in procedural code, references to globals are done using using a `global $varname;` declaration or `$GLOBALS['varname']`. Scopes don't inherit. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in PHP you have to use `$this->foo` to access an object field.
A simple `$foo` is interpreted as a local variable.

Example

```
class Test {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct($someVar) {
        $foo = $someVar; // here $foo is a local variable and its value will be dismissed
    }

    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$test = new Test('bar');
$result = $test->getFoo();
var_dump($result); // $result will be NULL instead of the expected 'bar'
```

Comment: I don't know but I reversed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP lacks lexical scopes and objects were implemented (if not still) as a table. This is why == tests memberwise on objects (which is bad BTW)

PHP has no concept of globals and locals, that's why you use globals you need need the global keyword - 'cept for superglobals, PHP is really quite messy in this regard.

Comment: 2 downvotes for stating facts?

Comment: I upvoted. Don't know who's downvoting

Comment: nonsense, complete nonsense

Comment: @JoeWatkins I know right?

Comment: @JoeWatkins you are clearly biased towards PHP and I am biased again - I hate it - it lacks LEXICAL scopes, that is why you need `$this` - if this were nonsense you wouldn't need `$this` (or it could be optional), this is because objects came really quite late into PHPs growth